LWC screen flow component to display a blank grid for data entry
I have created an LWC in one of our sandboxes that will allow data entry in the grid and save it to a variable to be used in the flow. A blank grid is displayed containing 5 columns and 15 rows. Data is entered across the grid and is supposed to save in the defined variables. The grid is not saving the entries that have been entered in the fields. I can enter data into box number 1 and after I move to box 2 data and the info from box 1 disappear. I have my variables defined in my flow for both input and output.



.HTML
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Check Input Grid">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                draft-values={draftValues}
                onsave={handleSave}
                oncellchange={handleCellChange}
            >
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

.JS
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import saveChecks from '@salesforce/apex/SaveCheckRecords.saveChecks';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Check Date', fieldName: 'checkDate', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'NPI', fieldName: 'npi', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { label: 'Tax ID', fieldName: 'taxId', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { label: 'Check Amount', fieldName: 'checkAmount', type: 'currency', editable: true }
];

export default class CheckInputGrid extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [
        { id: '1', checkDate: '', npi: '', taxId: '', checkAmount: 0 },
        { id: '2', checkDate: '', npi: '', taxId: '', checkAmount: 0 }
    ];
    @track draftValues = [];

    columns = columns;

    handleCellChange(event) {
        this.draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    }

    @api
    validate() {
        let isValid = true;
        let errorMessage = '';

        this.draftValues.forEach(draft => {
            const checkDate = draft.checkDate;
            const npi = draft.npi;
            const taxId = draft.taxId;
            const checkAmount = draft.checkAmount;

            // Validate date format MM/DD/YYYY
            const datePattern = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{4}$/;
            if (!datePattern.test(checkDate)) {
                isValid = false;
                errorMessage = 'Check Date must be in MM/DD/YYYY format.';
            }

            // Validate NPI as a 10-digit number
            if (!/^\d{10}$/.test(npi)) {
                isValid = false;
                errorMessage = 'NPI must be a 10-digit number.';
            }

            // Validate Tax ID as a 9-digit number
            if (!/^\d{9}$/.test(taxId)) {
                isValid = false;
                errorMessage = 'Tax ID must be a 9-digit number.';
            }

            // Validate check amount as a positive number
            if (checkAmount <= 0 || isNaN(checkAmount)) {
                isValid = false;
                errorMessage = 'Check Amount must be a positive number.';
            }
        });

        return {
            isValid: isValid,
            errorMessage: errorMessage
        };
    }

    handleSave() {
        const validation = this.validate();
        if (validation.isValid) {
            this.saveData();
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: validation.errorMessage,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }

    saveData() {
        const records = this.draftValues.map(draft => ({
            sobjectType: 'Checks__c',
            Check_Date__c: draft.checkDate,
            NPI__c: draft.npi,
            Tax_ID__c: draft.taxId,
            Check_Amount__c: draft.checkAmount
        }));

        saveChecks({ checks: records })
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Records saved successfully',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );

                // Clear draft values after saving
                this.draftValues = [];
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}

.XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="checkInputGrid">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>


From what I can see in the documentation, I think you're over-handling the oncellchange events. Is there a reason you are trying to override the draft-values property of the datatable every time that you change cell? This is handled already by the case component, so unless you're trying to do an incremental save, you don't have to concern yourself with tracking individual cell draft values. If you remove the draft-values={draftValues} and stop handling the cell changes, you can still reference the draft values when you save the data.
